# Getting different values in qnorm and summary function

Tags: r, statistics, cdf

I am new to R and was playing around with qnorm() and I noticed I am getting different values for qnorm() than showed in Summary().

Code:

```
set.seed(123)
X<-rnorm(100,10,1)
summary(X)
qnorm(0.5,10,1)
qnorm(0.25,10,1)
qnorm(0.75,10,1)
> summary(X)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  7.691   9.506  10.062  10.090  10.692  12.187 
> qnorm(0.5,10,1)
[1] 10
> qnorm(0.25,10,1)
[1] 9.32551
> qnorm(0.75,10,1)
[1] 10.67449
```

Shouldn't `qnorm()` of 0.25 be same as 1st quantile as `qnorm()` returns value for a particular cdf which can also be used to find a particular quantile ?

Comment: As @Oliver has shown practically in their answer, you are confusing the quantiles of the distribution (`qnorm`) with the quantiles of the observed/sampled data (`summary` or `quantile`).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is: No, but as n increases it will converge towards the same.

Consider `x <- rnorm(1, 10, 1)`, would you expect this single value to simultaneously to have the value of `qnorm(0.25, 10, 1)`, `qnorm(0.5, 10, 1)` and `qnorm(0.75, 10, 1)`? When simulating values you are drawing random lots from a distribution with certain properties. In this case it is a normal distribution with mean 10 and standard deviation 1, and the sample distribution will converge towards the theoretical distribution. But with 100 samples you should expect the observed sample distribution to deviate somewhat from the theoretical in terms of mean, standard deviation but even more so sample quantiles.

Try increasing `n` to a much bigger value (say 1e7), and you'll see the sample quantiles converging.

```
set.seed(123)
X<-rnorm(1E7,10,1)
summary(X)
qnorm(0.5,10,1)
qnorm(0.25,10,1)
qnorm(0.75,10,1)
```

Comment: I would add that the quantiles returned by `summary` can be obtained by the `quantile` function.